# Oracle Forms Default executable file location

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I am calling a oracle form from inside another form by using the following code .

```
declare
    pl_id ParamList;
    L_deptno NUMBER;
begin
    pl_id:=Get_Parameter_List('tmpdata');
    if not id_null(pl_id) then
         Destroy_Parameter_List(pl_id);
       Message('Paramlist already exists!!');
    end if;

    -- create parameter list
    pl_id:=Create_Parameter_List('tmpdata');
    if id_null(pl_id) then
         Message('Error occurned creating Param List');
         raise form_trigger_failure;
    end if;
    -- add parameter to the Param List
    -- Getting the Department_id of the employee
    select department_id into L_deptno from employees where employee_id=:EMP.employee_id;
    add_parameter(pl_id,'pm_deptno',text_parameter,L_deptno);
    --call the form
  CALL_FORM('empdepn',
              NO_hide,
              no_replace,
              no_query_only,
              pl_id);

   go_block('EMP');

 end;
```

however I am getting error - Cant find the form **empdepn** . Please note that I have kept fmb files for both of this forms in a random location. Where should I keep the files so that it can call the form?

Comment: Come on guys, please watch the tags. Your title clearly states "forms" and the content does too, yet the tags are far off. What has apex to do with this at all? Don't just click on all things that start with "oracle"?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Forms in 10G: There is 2 requirements to let the forms see each others:

1- you should add the forms locations into the registry (regedit -> navigate to the Oracle home and add the full path where the forms are located).

2- you should add an entry to the formsweb.cfg file, and create an environment file (.env).

Both forms should be compiled (.fmx files)

Answer (score 0):

In the formsweb.cfg for you configuration you can set a working_directory.
At this location the forms are found.

You could also make an environment file with a path variable, then forms will look at all these locations.